# How to find the percentage of employee scores using django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-annotate, django-aggregation

I have a table called Task. It captures task, task score and the employee it is assigned to.
I want to calculate the performance of the employee using his total task scores for the week (duration should be dynamic. preferably input field) and the total scores allocated.
I am thinking of aggregating the actual scores then dividing buy total score then multiply by 100 to get the percentage. My major challenge is where to perform this calculation. Should I create a model called performance and use a function? Or if can anyone show me how to go about this?

Here is the model;

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = model.CharField(max_length=200)
    scores = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the formula I want to use.  Performance(%) = actual score / total score * 100. Total score should be input field.

**UPDATE**
Here are the relevant models. I am using User model as Employee.

```
**USER OR EMPLOYEE MODEL**
 
class User(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
    ("STAFF", "Staff"),
    ("HOD", "Hod"),
    ("CEO", "Ceo"),
    )

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ("Male", "Male"),
    ("Female", "Female")
    )

    CONFIRMATION_CHOICES = (
        ("YES", "yes"),
        ("NO", "no")
    )

    UNDERTAKING_CHOICES = (
        ("YES", "yes"),
        ("NOT YET", "Not yet")
    )

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ("Male", "Male"),
        ("Female", "Female")
    )

    EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ("Permanent", "Permanent"),
        ("Contract", "Contract")
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    avatar =  models.ImageField(upload_to='images/avatar', null=True, blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='userdept', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name='userrol', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user_role = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatars", null=True, blank=True)
    is_hod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_ceo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    work_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    work_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    work_location = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    probation_length = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    pay_slip_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    can_terminate = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    employee_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    comfirmed = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CONFIRMATION_CHOICES, null=True)
    undertaking = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=UNDERTAKING_CHOICES, null=True)
    leave_days = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) 
    line_manager = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)   
    last_promotion_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+' '+self.last_name


**TASK MODEL**

from django.db import models
from departments.models import Department
from akps.models import Akp
from users.models import User
from goals.models import OrganisationGoal, OrganisationSubGoal, DepartmentGoal
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify
# from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Task(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ("COMPLETED", "completed"),
    ("FAILED", "failed"),
    )
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='soussdepartmentt', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    akp = models.ForeignKey(Akp, related_name='sousakpp', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    organisationgoal = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    organisationsubgoal = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationSubGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    departmentgoal = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='departgoal', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    assignedby = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taskassignb', null=True, blank=True)
    assignedto = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taskassignt', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='usertas', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    scores = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def clean(self):
        other_tasks = Task.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk) \
            .filter(departmentgoal=self.departmentgoal)

        if other_tasks.count() > 0:
            contributed = (
                other_tasks.values("departmentgoal")
                .annotate(total=models.Sum("scores"))
                .values_list("total", flat=True)[0]
            )
        else:
            contributed = 0

        if self.scores and self.scores + contributed > self.departmentgoal.scores:
            raise ValidationError({"scores": "Score is too much"})
```

Here is a scenario;

- user A has completed 8 out of  10 weekly task. He scored a total of 18 point. NOTE: Weekly scores can not exceed 20 points.
- The process above is repeated every week. Lets say the second week, he scored 20 points.
- After either 1 month, 4 months, 6 months or 1 year, I want to
  calculate his performance and display on his dashboard. The maths is actual score / total score * 100. I believe this can be achieve with the user and task model but i dont know how to implement this.

**USER AND DASHBOARD VIEW**

```
from tasks.models import Task
from users.models import User
from goals.models import DepartmentGoal, OrganisationGoal
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

def dashboard(request):
    
    completed_tasks = Task.objects.filter(status="COMPLETED", assignedto=request.user).count()
    failed_tasks = Task.objects.filter(status="FAILED", assignedto=request.user).count()

    debt_complt_goal = DepartmentGoal.objects.filter(status="COMPLETED", department=request.user.department).count()
    debt_failed_goal = DepartmentGoal.objects.filter(status="FAILED", department=request.user.department).count()

    complt_org_goals = OrganisationGoal.objects.filter(status="COMPLETED").count()
    failed_org_goals = OrganisationGoal.objects.filter(status="FAILED").count()

    return render (request, 'home.html', {
        'completed_tasks':completed_tasks, 
        'failed_tasks':failed_tasks, 
        'debt_complt_goal':debt_complt_goal,
        'debt_failed_goal':debt_failed_goal,
        'complt_org_goals':complt_org_goals,
        'failed_org_goals':failed_org_goals,
    })



from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, HttpResponse
from .models import Profile, User
from .forms import ProfileForm, CreateUserForm, UserSetPasswordForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages


def list_users_view(request):
    department = request.user.department
    dept_users = User.objects.filter(department=department)
    users = User.objects.all()
    context = {
        'users':users,
        'dept_users':dept_users
        }
    return render(request, 'users/list-users.html', context)
```

Comment: what is the total score here ? the sum of all score or a fixed value ?

Comment: If weekly task score is 20points but the employee score 10points. What will be his scores in percent if you are to implement it in Django?

Comment: I need some more information to understand your problem better. What does your Employee model look like and which field in the `Task` model relates back to an instance of the `Employee`? How can you calculate a weekly aggregation when there are no date/datetime fields on the model?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I edited the question. I believe this answers your question.

Comment: @ThaddeausIorbee ok, I'm getting a clearer picture now. What's the difference between the `assignedto` and `user` fields in the `Task` model? And which of these two fields do you use to associate the task to the user (I'm guessing `assignedto`)?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr assignedto is the user that has been assigned a task.  you guessed right.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I am a bit confuse. I dont know how to call ```user.performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())``` in my existing view.  I updated my question with the relevant views. The dashboard view and the user view. Kindly show me how I will call this class method. I want each user to be able to view their performance on their dashboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the criteria that I interpreted:

1. A task is associated with a user using the `assignedto` field.
2. The task has a due date which will be used against the time range parameters when calculating performance.
3. The task is either completed or failed.
4. If the user completes the task, the user will acquire the score associated with the task.

**Solution**

Add a custom method on your `User` model to calculate the performance. The method will ask for a `start` and `end` date arguments to calculate the performance between a time range.

```py
from django.db.models import Sum, Q


class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

    def performance(self, start, end):
        actual = Sum("scores", filter=Q(status="completed"))

        q = self.taskassignt.filter(
            due_date__gte=start,
            due_date__lt=end  # `end` is excluded from the range
        ).annotate(actual=actual, total=Sum("scores"))

        return (q[0].actual / q[0].total) * 100
```

Note the time range implementation excludes `end` from the range since it uses the `lt` (less than) operator.

Usage of the method is:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta


# user is a `User` instance
user.performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I will implement and get back.

Comment: I am a bit confuse. I dont know how to call ```user.performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())``` in my existing view. I updated my question with the relevant views. The dashboard view and the user view. Kindly show me how I will call this class method. I want each user to be able to view their performance on their dashboard.

Comment: @ThaddeausIorbee Since your user is `request.user`, you call the method with `request.user.performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())`. Note, that the arguments passed into the method is a time range of a week. You can pass whatever date arguments you want into the method, so long as they are date types.

Comment: I marked this answer correct because it is so close to solving my problem. Thanks @Scratch'N'Purr and everyone that contributed.

Comment: Can you figure out where this error coming from?
```performance = get_performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())
TypeError: get_performance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end' ```

Comment: Your missing an argument in your `get_performance` function. Did you rename `performance` to `get_performance`?

Comment: yes. I renamed the method performance to get_performance then stored it in a variable called performance in the table. My aim is to call it user.performance in the template.

Comment: @ Scratch'N'Purr  ```performance = get_performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())```   This is what i did. What is the the argument i need to pass?

Comment: The arguments start and end are present in the variable performance. Why te error?

Comment: You need to also specify the user instance calling the method since it's a class method. So if your instance is `user`, it should be `user.get_performance(...)` because there's a special argument called `self` which refers to the class instance that is calling the method.

Comment: ```IndexError: list index out of range``` this is the error that shows up when I call ```user.performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())```  in views.py

Answer (score 0):

I can't totally map this to your model above because you're missing a few things like user mapping and timestamps, but it should be something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

end_date = datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=7)
performance = Sum(F('scores')) / (Count(F('scores')) * 100)
Task.objects.filter(
    employee_id=123, 
    timestamp__gt=start_date, 
    timestamp__lte=end_date
).aggregate(
    performance=performance
)
```

Comment: Hi @shapiromatron, thanks for your prompt response. All this will be a function in Task model? I am a beginner in django.

Comment: yes it could be a class method on the task model or you can get fancy and subclass the query set. If it’s just a few then i’d make a new class method on the task model.

Comment: Ok. I will implement it when I am home. I will notify you of the outcome. 
It means I will create a performance field on the Task Model right? Since performance = performance.

Comment: No, this is a query, not something that you'd store in the database, at least in the current model. you could create a new database table with this aggregate result.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will get back.