# How to pass concatenated functions as a argument in django model method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-model-field

I am trying to pass `timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2)` and `timezone.now()` as arguments in django model method but  am getting

```
def performance(user, timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2), timezone.now()):
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know the error is as a result of the concatenation but I dont know how to solve this problem.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    .........................
    fields
    .........................

    def get_performance(self, timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2), timezone.now()):

        actual = Sum("scores", filter=Q(status="completed"))

        q = self.taskassignt.filter(
            due__gte=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2),
            due__lt=timezone.now() 
        ).annotate(actual=actual, total=Sum("scores"))

        return (q[0].actual / q[0].total) * 100
```

Comment: What is `q[0]` supposed to do? Why are we only interested in the *first* related `taskassignt`?

Comment: you have to set a argument like  `something = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a parameter name, so

```
def get_performance(self, start_time=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2), end_time=timezone.now()):
    actual = Sum("scores", filter=Q(status="completed"))
    q = self.taskassignt.filter(
        due__gte=start_time,
        due__lt=end_time 
    ).annotate(actual=actual, total=Sum("scores"))

    return 100 * q[0].actual / q[0].total
```

But this will not work, since the default value will be initialized *once* and then be used each time. That means that if your server is running for an entire year, `start_time` will still be the time from th previous year.

Usually one works with a `None` as default value, and if the parameter is indeed `None`, substitute it with a given expression, so:

```
def get_performance(self, start_time=None, end_time=None):
    if start_time is None:
        start_time = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2)
    if end_time is None:
        end_time = timezone.now()
    actual = Sum("scores", filter=Q(status="completed"))
    q = self.taskassignt.filter(
        due__gte=start_time,
        due__lt=end_time 
    ).annotate(actual=actual, total=Sum("scores"))

    return 100 * q[0].actual / q[0].total
```

It is however odd to have a `100 * q[0].actual / q[0].total`. This means that you are only intersted in the *first* `taskassignt`, not in all. Likely you want to [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) instead of [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
def get_performance(self, start_time=None, end_time=None):
    if start_time is None:
        start_time = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2)
    if end_time is None:
        end_time = timezone.now()
    actual = Sum("scores", filter=Q(status='completed'))
    q = self.taskassignt.filter(
        due__gte=start_time,
        due__lt=end_time 
    ).aggregate(actual=actual, total=Sum("scores"))

    return 100 * q['actual'] / q['total']
```

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem Kindly look at this thread. My aim is to calculate emplayee either weekly, quarterly or yearly performance from task. each task carries scores. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644458/how-to-find-the-percentage-of-employee-scores-using-django/69038881?noredirect=1#comment122174650_69038881

Comment: ```IndexError: list index out of range``` this is the error that shows up when I call ```user.performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2), timezone.now())```  in views.py